# After installing windows 10 1903 July 21, 2020-KB4562900 updates few of the keys have stopped working

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

After running windows 10 1903 updates July 21, 2020-KB4562900 Cumulative Update Preview for .NET Framework  on 30th July few of the keys have stopped working. The keys 0, 9, o, l, ., up down right left keys are not functioning. Uninstalled the quality update and even tried to uninstall from Advance Options but after uninstalling the update, again it had installed two other updates KB4560960 and KB4565633.  The windows application log show the event 'The program explorer.exe version 10.0.18362.959 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. Log Name: Application  Source: Application Hang  Date: 30-07-2020 19:37:11  Event ID: 1002'  exact during the time the key blocking issue start to show up.

When tried to update the Standard PS/2 keyboard driver from the Device Manager it show 'The best driver for the device are already installed' message. Even after all this the keys are still not functioning.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem

Answer (score 1):

Keys in a distinct "stripe" not working is more an indication the underlying circuit board has been physically damaged; whether by impact or due to a swollen battery.

Test with an external keyboard to eliminate simple software conflict, but it probably needs the services of a professional.

Answer (score 0):

.Net Framework Updates may be waiting to still run, but that will not affect keyboard keys.

Use the manufacturer's Driver Update application and update BIOS, Chipset (if there is one) and all other drivers. Make sure all drivers are up to date.

Then restart and do Windows Updates again.  V1903 is out of support or very nearly so, so Updates will move you to a supported version.

After all the above, also try the suggestion in the other post:  External Keyboard.